# MemSQL node failed to start

Tags: singlestore

When I tried today to start my cluster I get the following error

> MemSQL node CCBA806E30C9A8E4430ADFEAF5DF435ED91B8F7F failed to start:
>   Failed to connect to MemSQL node
>   CCBA806E30C9A8E4430ADFEAF5DF435ED91B8F7F: No error in tracelog

and the worst part is that I am not able to query anything. I get this error whenever I query.

> ERROR 1777 (HY000): Partition memsqldb:0 has no master instance.

What is the exact problem here?

Comment: Hey Ysaditya - please join the MemSQL chat so we can help you debug this issue: chat.memsql.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried running  **​memsql-ops report​**

> memsql-ops report
>
> 2015-10-10 09:51:10: Jf3fc7e04 [INFO] Building a diagnostic report for agent A0cd4d79612c64a1298c66f7d346fe44a
>
> 2015-10-10 09:51:20: Jf3fc7e04 [WARNING] Could not get info for MemSQL node 378F1F82DE7DE6A3D4552A381F316399A579DF18: [Errno 2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.104.184' (4)

figured out that the problem is with IPs as my IP at my office is different from that of my Home.So i did as follows

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --dest 192.168.104.184 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.69.0.2 
memsql-ops cluster-start
```

This solved the Problem.